# Insert multiple rows - SQL Error: near ",": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

In my SQLite I want to insert 2 rows.

```
INSERT INTO notification_invoice (amount,currencyISOCode) VALUES
 (1.1,'498'),
 (34.2,'980');
```

But I get error:

> 30-Nov-18 12:21:21: SQL Error: near ",": syntax error  INSERT INTO
>   notification_invoice (amount,currencyISOCode) VALUES  (1.1,'498'), 
>   (34.2,'980');
>    >

Comment: What DB engine do you use? Terradata?

Comment: I use DB: SQLite

Comment: @Alexei Which version? It looks like you run sqlite 2 while the syntax you use for multiple line inserts is only supported since sqlite 3.7.

Comment: @sloth Yes, you was right. After I update sqlite drivers - it's work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)